# Dianoga issue with SVG images

Tags: svg, sitecore, webp

I am using Dianoga with Sitecore 8.2 to optimize the images. It works fine for jpg, gif, png extension, but it has issues with SVG images. Once we access the SVG image, Dianoga works in the backend to optimize the image. I have verified this by checking the logs

> 38020 20:12:54 INFO  Dianoga: optimized /Images/aj.svg [original size]
>   (final size: 16372 bytes) - saved 116247 bytes / 87.65%. Optimized in
>   16872ms. 38100 20:12:54 INFO  Dianoga: optimized /Images/aj.svg
>   [original size] (final size: 16372 bytes) - saved 116247 bytes /
>   87.65%. Optimized in 16448ms.

Where it says that aj.svg is optimized by 87.65% and no error after that. It means SVG image is successfully optimized. Now if we try to refresh the web page after clearing the browser cache I am not able the see the optimized cache.

To troubleshoot I followed the below steps

1. Checked the media cache where i find the WebP file is created
2. I clicked on WebP file it shows a blank page as below

[image: SVG Blank image]

So, it seems that Dianoga is able to optimize the SVG image, but failed to convert to WebP.

Answer (score 0):

[Dianoga 5.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dianoga/5.0.0) has just been released with a number of fixes for *SVG* & *WebP* processing failures and full *WebP* support in both CM including media library uploads & CD for on-the-fly conversions of *png*, *gif* & *jpeg* to *WebP*. Find more details about the 5th release [here](https://github.com/kamsar/Dianoga/releases/tag/5.0.0).

So, it is worth trying for better productivity and stability of your Sitecore website.